# How to match last 9 digit of number with space flutter

Tags: regex, flutter

I tried to match only the 9 digits of phone number

I have multi input

```
+33123456789
```

or

```
0123456789
```

or

```
+33 01 23 45 67 89
```

or

```
01 23 45 67 89
```

I want one output `123456789`

currently I have found how to match 
   +33123456789
or
   0123456789

with (\d{9}$)

But I don't find how to match with space between

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use repeat matching a digit followed by 0+ times a space 8 times. For the last digit you could also match 0+ times a space and a digit and capture that in a group.

After the captured group match 0* times a space and assert the end of the string.

`((?:\d *){8} *\d) *$`

**Explanation**

- `(` Capturing group

  - `(?:\d *){8}` Repeat 8 times a non capturing group that matches a digit and 0+ times a space
  - `*\d` match 0+ times a space followed by a digit
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `*$` Match 0+ times a space and assert the end of the string

The 9 digits including whitespace between them are in the first capturing group.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dWCyR4/1)

Comment: Sorry i speak too quickly,I search to remove white space in all output like 123456789 even if my input have whitespace

Comment: One way could be to replace all whitespaces of group 1 with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
(?:\+\d{2}\ ?)?(\d[\d ]*\d)
```

and use the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/YmiWSf/2/).